# Is it OK to contact a recruiter and ask how long does it usually take to go through the recruitment process?

Tags: job-search, germany

I have a 1 year contract job in the IT industry that will end in April, which will probably renewed into a unlimited contract.
I am thinking about not renewing the contract and change to a new company when the contract ends. (If I do not find anything when the contract ends, I will renew it).

I still have approximately 4 months, so I think it is a little bit early to prepare CVs and so on. But I would not like to get the new job 2 weeks after renewing the contract.

Is it OK to contact a recruiter and ask how long does it usually take to go through the recruitment process?

btw: I am in Germany. As a "fresh" foreigner I do not know the "job culture" yet.

Comment: When you say "recruiter", do you mean an internal one (HR or hiring manager) for companies where you applied for a job posting or an external recruiter/agency?

Comment: To add to Lilienthal's question, a recruitment agent could not answer this as it's very company dependent.  They could perhaps tell you how long a particular organisation takes, but only if they've had experience with them before.

Comment: Prepare your CV today. The long form of the CV should never be out of date.

Comment: In order to answer the question properly, any recruiter would have to make the assumption that not only are you employable, but you are a desired employee and thus likely to be snatched up quickly.  The problem is when you are neither of those things, and the job market requirement doesnt reflect your actual skills or experience, and so you don't get any offers...  A recruiter cannot guarantee you work or even interviews, they can only guarantee you that they will send your details out, so any reasonable recruiter wont give you an answer to that question...

Comment: 4 months can be a short time, depending how fast the hiring company makes appointments, decision, etc. So I would start preparing your CV and applying,

Comment: It is a good idea to have a cv that is always up to date. Revise it every 3 months or when you get a new job

Answer (score 3):

It's absolutely fine to contact them, give them your CV, make sure your LinkedIn page is up-to-date, and tell them that you are available in 4 months time, and that the perfect start for a new job would be two weeks after that.

They will happily put that in their database and start spamming you immediately with jobs that are not what you want, start too early, start too late and so on, but that's what they do anyway if they get hold of your details, so you don't lose anything. And within all that spam hopefully there is your perfect job hidden somewhere.

If they don't know that you exist then they won't do anything for you.

Since a three month notice period is not unusual in Germany, companies will be quite willing to wait a bit, so with luck you'd sign a contract for a new job within a month or two.